# How do I scan my Routers Ports?

Tags: ports, scan

I recently scanned ports from within my LAN, but I recently read in order to determine whether Ports are open to the WAN I need to scan from outside the LAN, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for a way to access it from the outside look at an external VPN or use Tor

https://tor.eff.org

Using nmap from an external network is probably the easiest and most thorough way to make sure you scan everything. Note: Many services and security tools completely skip ports 9100 and port 0, some skip everything that's not particularly popular at a given time. Be thorough about your testing method to ensure you have tested all possible ports.

https://nmap.org/

Make sure you check all ports on each interface from that interfaces respective network. Likewise make sure you scan the TCP ports, UDP ports, IP services, and IPv6 if you have that configured.

The following commands will help:

TCP scans

nmap -n -Pn --allports -p 0-65535

UDP scans (Note: You may need to run UDP scans slowly to ensure packets are not lost)

nmap -n -Pn --allports -sU -p0-65535

IP Services Scan

nmap -n -Pn -sO

etc...

Likewise it may also be helpful to run some of the tests with the nmap NSE sripts which can be found here:

https://nmap.org/nsedoc/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shields Up!](https://www.grc.com/shieldsup). It allows a scan of all the ports of your router as seen from Internet.